# why is my beta different from yahoo finance?

Tags: python, covariance, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance

I have some code which calculates the beta of the S&P 500 vs any stock - in this case the ticker symbol "FET". However the result seems to be completely different from what I am seeing on yahoo finance, historical this stock has been very volatile and that would explain the beta value of 1.55 on yahoo finance - http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=fet. Can someone please advise as to why I am seeing a completely different number (0.0088)? Thanks in advance.

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import numpy
import sys

today = date.today()

stock_one = DataReader('FET','yahoo',datetime(2009,1,1), today)
stock_two = DataReader('^GSPC','yahoo',stock_one['Adj Close'].keys()[0], today)


a = stock_one['Adj Close'].pct_change()
b = stock_two['Adj Close'].pct_change()

covariance = numpy.cov(a[1:],b[1:])[0][1]
variance = numpy.var(b[1:])

beta = covariance / variance

print 'beta value ' + str(beta)
```

Comment: Hum, when I ran your code i got this error: ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: Seems the number of days pulled for stock 1 is 710 and for stock 2 is 709. Might want to start there.

Comment: yeah i got the same error for ticker aapl!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I played with the code a bit and this is what I have.

```
 from pandas.io.data import DataReader
import pandas.io.data as web
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import numpy
import sys

start = datetime(2009, 1, 1)
today = date.today()
stock1 = 'AAPL'
stock2 = '^GSPC'

stocks = web.DataReader([stock1, stock2],'yahoo', start, today)
# stock_two = DataReader('^GSPC','yahoo', start, today)

a = stocks['Adj Close'].pct_change()

covariance = a.cov() # Cov Matrix
variance = a.var() # Of stock2 
var = variance[stock2]

cov = covariance.loc[stock2, stock1]

beta = cov / var

print "The Beta for %s is: " % (stock2), str(beta)
```

The length of the prices did not equal each other, so there was problem #1. Also when your final line executed found the beta for every value of the cov matrix, which is probably not what you wanted. You don't need to know what the beta is based on cov(0,0) and cov(1,1), you just need to look at cov(0,1) or cov(1,0). Those are the positions in the matrix not the values.

Anyway, here is the answer I got:

```
The Beta for ^GSPC is:  0.885852632799
```

*** Edit ***

Made the code easier to run, and changed it so there is only one line for inputting what stocks you want to pull from Yahoo.

Comment: close, but try it with AAPL, the script fails

Comment: almost there but now I am getting 0.512076334094 for FET!

Comment: Your beta is never going to be exactly the same. Because the data is not cleaned after it is pulled from Yahoo it will be subject to splits and other adjustments. If you are looking for data to trade on, you need to find a higher quality data source.

Comment: Also about the Beta Yahoo uses: The Beta used is Beta of Equity. Beta is the monthly price change of a particular company relative to the monthly price change of the S&P500. The time period for Beta is 3 years (36 months) when available.

Comment: For other questions on why your numbers from Yahoo might come out different, see their help page here: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/finance/SLN2347.html?impressions=true

Comment: I've answered your question. If you don't think so, post why.

Comment: well i was looking for something to measure the beta which would be remotely close to the results I see in yahoo finance, although this does not accomplish it I will accept the answer as it is the closest we have managed to get to what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the closing Px into correct format for calculation.  These prices should be converted into return percentages for both the index and the stock price.

Comment: You should also be using excess returns, i.e. returns minus some notion of the risk-free rate. You might also look at whether there is a discrepancy in the degrees of freedom used for calculating covariance natively in numpy vs. whatever method was used for the Yahoo-reported value. The ddof keyword in Python for these kinds of things can sometimes make a significant difference. You might be better off just running it as an actual regression with, e.g. pandas.ols, instead of using the covariance-variance formula.

Comment: Ok I have made changes to reflect changes in closed prices as percentages, although it looks a little better I am still seeing discrepancies between the python code results and yahoo finance

Answer (score 1):

In order to match Yahoo finance, you need to use three years'  of monthly Adjusted Close prices.

https://help.yahoo.com/kb/finance/SLN2347.html?impressions=true

> Beta
>
> The Beta used is Beta of Equity. Beta is the monthly price change of a
>   particular company relative to the monthly price change of the S&P500.
>   The time period for Beta is 3 years (36 months) when available.